# How to push stuff in the array inside another array in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a User schema with a message field which looks like this:

```
messages: [{
      receiver: {
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      history: [{
        user: {
          type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User'
        },
        message: {
          type: String
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now
        }
      }]
    }]
```

I'm adding `user` in `message` array this way:

```
await User.update({_id: userID }, {$push: {"messages": {"$each" : [{user: friendID}]}}})
```

How could I add an object inside `history` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the positional operator (`<array>.$`) to match the message you want to update and then `$push` to the history array within that message.

Note that as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_):

> The positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the *first* element that matches the query document.

Therefore it might be useful to have an `_id` or some unique identifier for each message in your array. I didn't see something like that in your schema, though. If you use `user`, then it will match the first message with that `user`.

You code would therefore be something like:

```
User.update({ 
  _id: userId,
  "messages.<uniqueIdKey>": <uniqueIdValue>, 
}, 
{
  $push: {
    "messages.$.history": <objectToPush>
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm using receiver id as a unique key.  So this worked fine: `await User.update({_id: userID, "messages.receiver": friendID,},{$push: {"messages.$.history": {user: friendID, message: message}},});`